# Log4j2, no logs in file

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to configure log4j2 within a maven project without a standard structure, but even though the file is created nothing is appended.

I have the following dependencies in the pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am using the following versions

```
    <properties>
        <slf4j-version>1.7.21</slf4j-version>
        <log4j-version>2.6.2</log4j-version>
        <jackson-version>2.8.2</jackson-version>
    </properties>
```

and the following log4j2.properties

```
status = info
rootLogger.level = info

name = PropertiesConfig
property.fileName = ./log/log.txt

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${fileName}
appender.rolling.filePattern = ./log/log_%d{dd-MM-yy}.txt
appender.rolling.append = true

appender.rolling.layout.type = JSONLayout
appender.rolling.layout.complete = true

appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true

appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5
```

Also, because of the project's structure I am setting the property file like this

```
    LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    File file = new File(CONFIGURATION_DIR + File.separator + "log4j2.properties");

    // this will force a reconfiguration
    context.setConfigLocation(file.toURI());
```

Even though the file gets created nothing is appended to the file and I have no errors. Am I missing something, or doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I was missing the following configurations for the log4j2.properties file :

```
logger.rolling.name = name
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

Now it works.